# Web API with MongoDB issue

Tags: c#, mongodb

Pretty new to C# and MongoDB, I am following [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1267/using-mongodb-nosql-database-with-aspnet-webapi-core) tutorial (which I understand is a bit outdated) however I am working through it and fixing the deprecation. I am struggling with this portion of code from the tutorial:

```
 public Product GetProduct(ObjectId id)
    {
        var res = Query<Product>.EQ(p=>p.Id,id);
        return _db.GetCollection<Product>("Products").FindOne(res);
    }
```

I am was getting errors on this line specifically `var res = Query<Product>.EQ(e => e.Id, id);` and have since tweaked it to the following...

```
 public Post GetPost(ObjectId id)
    {
        var res = IQueryable<Product>.Equals(p =>p.id, id);
        return _db.GetCollection<Product>("Product").Find(res);
    }
```

My issue is that it does like the lambda expression and gives me this error `cannot convert lambda expression to type object because it is not a delegate type`. so what I am asking is the following...

1.What is the point of this lambda?

2.How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Builders to create your filter:

```
var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
return _db.GetCollection<Product>("Product").Find(filter);
```

Or just use the lambda directly in the Find() method, i.e

```
public Post GetPost(ObjectId id)
{
    //If using FindOne() you won't need FirstOrDefault()
    return _db.GetCollection<Product>("Product").Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```